# Java plug-in into the prepackaged Eclipse PHP

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Have installed PHP eclipse, now i need to run my java code as well.

Can any one help me to install java plug-in into the prepackaged Eclipse PHP.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Open 'Help > Install New Software....'

In 'Work with' choose your main Eclipse installation (`http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars` for Eclipse Mars)

In the 'Programming Languages' section choose 'Eclipse Java Development Tools'